# Setting variables based on build type in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm building an application that interfaces between two third party services. Both of these third party services can utilize a sandbox environment, which uses a different URL, username, and password. I need to come up with some method of denoting if my build should be utilizing the sandbox or production as efficiently as possible.

Currently, I have a global static class that houses a boolean called `isDebug`, and I'm using a ternary operator on every single value that could be different between debug and production. These values include: URLs, usernames, passwords, form IDs, user IDs, etc. Is there an efficient way of setting these values, like in the web.config or otherwise?

Example of the global class:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static bool InDebug = false;

    public static readonly string Service1 = InDebug ? "https://example1.com" : "https://sandbox.example1.com";
}
```

and in my inner classes

```
public struct ZdForms
{
    public static readonly long DefaultForm = GlobalVariables.InDebug ? 91267 : 140508;
    public static readonly long IssueForm = GlobalVariables.InDebug ? 91257 : 34708;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have 2 separate deployment locations for my application on our servers. One is a sandbox test bed that interfaces with the services' sandboxes. So when I publish to these locations, I want to have the correct values propagated.

Comment: This is the exact purpose of config files. In the simplest case, I would rename `GlobalVariables` to something like `Config`, and have something like `public string Service1 { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Service1Url"]; } }`

Comment: @JasonP I was sure something like that was the case. It'll just require some serious reworking on my end as I designed the application a bit wonky the first time.

Comment: As you try this out, also consider caching settings if it makes sense for your application, or creating an `IConfiguration` interface with the settings as properties. You could implement it however you wanted, and easily change it later. You could use the web.config, a SQL table, an Azure table, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Configuration Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) to store these values in the `.config` file.  The transformation is applied based on the selected build configuration automatically.

Tranfromations include the ability add, remove, or modify different parts of the config file using `XPath syntax`.

Example:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AWLT" connectionString="newstring"
       providerName="newprovider"
       xdt:Transform="Replace" 
       xdt:Locator="Condition(@name='oldname'
         or @providerName='oldprovider')" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The transformation file is named `web.<configuration name>.config` and placed along side the web.config file.  The easiest way to add one is to right-click the web.config file and "Add Configuration Transform".

Comment: So would this work in my given context? Would it allow me to define a whole series of values to populate into my variables? Or would I have to fetch them like settings?

Comment: You would need to read them out of the config file like any other configuration entry. This just allows you to "mutate" the config file automatically at build time based on the selected build configuration.

Comment: Is there any method of making this work from within visual studio during debug?

Comment: Yes, it's based on the build configuration. just create alternate debug / release build configurations for each set of config mutations you want. then simply use the drop down o the toolbar to choose the configuration you want to build.

Comment: They only seems to affect deployments, not visual studio builds.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use the [`#if` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx).

For example, this...

```
public static readonly string Service1 = InDebug
    ? "https://example1.com"
    : "https://sandbox.example1.com";
```

Would become...

```
#if DEBUG
    public static readonly string Service1 = "https://example1.com";
#else
    public static readonly string Service1 = "https://sandbox.example1.com";
#endif
```

When you compile under Debug, only the top `Service1` will get compiled. When you compile under any other build, the bottom `Service1`. This may work OK for a Debug/Release situation but if you start needing more configurations, your source is going to get cluttered with these directives... In that situation, using configuration files with transforms is likely the best way.

Also, you will end up with 2 different binaries -- one for Debug and one for not.

You can define additional directive constants for each configuration under project properties > Build > Conditional compilation symbols (separated by space).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this really work since I'm actually deploying the sandbox version to a remote server.